# Spring Batch and Spring MVC - Best design approach

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

We have a web application written on SpringMVC. Also, we have some need of running code through batch application (Spring scheduler). Code re-usability view, we thought  to have batch code as well part of the application and then generated JAR out of which.

Is it best way to do so having batch and application code part of the same application. Or do we need separate batch application?

Please advise the best design approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Is both are part of same business? As you have to run Spring Batch in background to do some process, it would be better to keep it separate from Spring MVC Application. Each application should be part of one type of business.

First find out how much dependencies are there for making it separate.